# Run Time Polymorphism

Tags: java

```
class A {
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("From Class A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("From Class B");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(Strings[] args){

        A a = new A();
        A b = new B()
        a.display();
        b.display();
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
From Class A    
From Class B
```

Now, I am getting the output as expected.
But I want to know why I am using `A b = new B()`, when same thing I can achieve by using
`B b = new B()`.
What is the advantage of using former techniques, where and when it is beneficial for me?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface - not quite the question you asked, but you should find the answers enlightening.

Comment: Also take a look at this discussion: [Understanding “programming to an interface”](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface).

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example here. We all know birds can fly, but there are some exceptions. We know from their behavior, so lets model this.

Generally, birds can fly, so:

```
class Bird {
  void fly() {
      System.out.println("I can fly");
    }
 }

class Eagle extends Bird {
      void fly() {
        System.out.println("I can fly very high");
    }
}
```

We all know that ducks can't fly, but we don't say it for all birds. We say at runtime whether a specific bird can fly or not, depending on the bird.

```
class Duck extends Bird {
      void fly() {
        System.out.println("I can walk or swim only");
    }
}

class FlightDemo {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Bird bird = new Bird();
         bird.fly(); // output: I can fly

         Bird eagle = new Eagle();
         eagle.fly(); // output: I can fly very high

         Bird duck = new Duck();
         duck.fly(); // output: I can walk or swim only
      }
}
```

You saw that at runtime it's decided that ducks can't fly. You can override its fly behavior and it would walk or swim. We saw that Duck IS a Bird, and it can't fly, so we have overridden its behavior, and still Duck IS a Bird, and it can walk or swim.

Comment: Irfan@ What is wrong in writing like:  
Duck duck = new Duck();
duck.fly();
will I not achieve the same functionality.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but that's not polymorphic. Bird decides at runtime which behavior it should assign, a duck or an eagle or just a bird.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it doesn't matter which way you chose. Your example doesn't show the power of polymorphism.

Let's see a trivial example of Polymorphism:

[image]

```
interface Shape{
    void draw();
}

class Rectangle implements Shape{
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Drawing Rectangle.");
    }
}

class Triangle implements Shape{
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Drawing Triangle.");
    }
}

class Circle implements Shape{
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Drawing Circle.");
    }
}
```

`Rectangle`, `Triangle`, and `Circle` are just implementing their own definition of `draw` function.

Now, suppose you've to implement a `drawAllShapes` method in your `Main` class, which takes a bunch of shapes and print them all. But without polymorphism this can be hectic, as there can be different types of shapes. Now, here comes polymorphism to save us.

```
class RandomShapeFactory{
    public static Shape createRandomShape(){
        Shape randomShape;

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNo = random.nextInt() % 3 + 1;
        if (randomNo == 1){
            randomShape = new Rectangle();
        }
        else if (randomNo == 2){
            randomShape = new Triangle();
        }
        else{
            randomShape = new Circle();
        }
        return randomShape;
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Shape[] shapes = new Shape[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++){
            shapes[i] = RandomShapeFactory.createRandomShape();
        }
        drawAllShapes(shapes);
    }

    public static void drawAllShapes(Shape[] shapes){
        for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++){
            shapes[i].draw();
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation of `drawAllShapes` doesn't have to know whether the `Shape` at index `i` is a `Circle` or `Triangle` or what, whichever `Shape` it is, it just calls their implementation of the `draw` method.

`main` method has all random shapes, and when passed to the `drawAllShapes` method, their relative implementations are invoked.

This kind of implementation also follows the [*Open/Closed Principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), that if you want, in future, to add some more Shapes to the hierarchy, `drawAllShapes` method doesn't have to know about the new shapes either, just add new classes and implement the `Shape` interface, and `drawAllShapes` will work with those shapes too.

See the above example in action [here](http://ideone.com/faYsDx).

Comment: Your answer is more towards software design principles and patterns instead of basic principle of run-time polymorphism.

Comment: I think, the question was, why to use base class reference, and invoke the principle of run-time polymorphism instead of using the reference of the actual class itself. So I just tried to show the power of polymorphism with an example.